# How should I instantiate a ViewModel in a Fragment? It works fine in an activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have a working code while it's placed on an activity. But when I want to use the same code in a fragment, it's not working. I guess instantiation of the ViewModel in a Fragment takes in different arguments. I'd appreciate your input. Thanks

I am following the documentation implemtation of a viewmodel as shown below.
**Implementation according to documentation**

[image]

**Access: According to Documentation**
[image]

**Here's the instantiation in the activity, but not working in Fragment.**

```
 private val hymnViewModel: HymnViewModel by viewModels {
        HymnViewModelFactory((application as HymnsApplication).repository)
    }
```

**Inside onCreate**

```
hymnViewModel.allHymns.observe(this, Observer { words ->
            // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
            words?.let { adapter.submitList(it) }
        })*/
```

**My View Model:**

```
class HymnViewModel(private val repository: HymnRepository) : ViewModel() {

    // Using LiveData and caching what allHymns returns has several benefits:
    // - We can put an observer on the data (instead of polling for changes) and only update the
    //   the UI when the data actually changes.
    // - Repository is completely separated from the UI through the ViewModel.
    val allHymns: LiveData<List<Hymn>> = repository.allHymns.asLiveData()

    /**
     * Launching a new coroutine to insert the data in a non-blocking way
     */
    fun insert(hymn: Hymn) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.insert(hymn)
    }
}

class HymnViewModelFactory(private val repository: HymnRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(HymnViewModel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return HymnViewModel(repository) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain in greater detail what "it's not working" means? You might also want to look into using a dependency inversion framework, such as Koin, that lets you avoid creating your own `ViewModelProvider.Factory` classes.

Comment: Hello @CommonsWare, thank you for the inquiry and suggestion. Kindly, when I try to access the viewmodel from the activity, it is OK. But when I use the same code to access the same viewModel from a Fragment, it is not displaying anything at all. That's the problem.

Comment: "it is not displaying anything at all" -- your question does not show how you are trying to use the viewmodel. Between breakpoints and logging, you should be able to determine where things are going wrong, more specifically than what you have described so far.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I'll reframe my reply and I will include it in an edited version of the question

Comment: Using breakpoints and logging, you can determine whether your observer (`observe { ... }`) is getting called or not. From there, you can start determining what is wrong with your repository, such that you are not getting your results.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks. However, my repository is totally working fine. I tested that with an activity and all works well. Only that I have changed from using an Activity to using a Fragment and I have fallen short of how to call the viewmodel in the Fragment. Thanks

Comment: "my repository is totally working fine" -- based on your symptoms and your code, I suspect that you are being overly optimistic. Regardless, **using breakpoints and logging**, you are doing to need to debug your app. We cannot help you do that.

Comment: Thanks. Not being overly optimistic, but what I meant is that I was able to display contents of the database on a recyclerview on the activity.

Comment: Is the problem that you're not getting the same ViewModel instance that the Activity has? If you want the same instance as the Activity, use `by activityViewModels` instead of `by viewModels`

Comment: @Tenfour04, thank you so much! It worked! I used activityViewModels as you suggested and in the observe function, I replaced "this" with "viewLifeCycleOwner". The recyclerview in the fragment is now fetching and displaying all items! I can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

After @Tenfour04's suggestion, the Fragment now has the same ViewModel instance as the Activity. Here's what I replaced:

**The ViewModel:**

```
class HymnViewModel(private val repository: HymnRepository) : ViewModel() {

    /**
     * Launching a new coroutine to insert the data in a non-blocking way
     */
    fun insert(hymn: Hymn) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.insert(hymn)
    }
}

class HymnViewModelFactory(private val repository: HymnRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(HymnViewModel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return HymnViewModel(repository) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

**Iniatialized my ViewModel in the fragment as**

```
private lateinit var viewModel: HymnViewModel
    private val hymnViewModel: HymnViewModel by activityViewModels {
        HymnViewModelFactory((context?.applicationContext as HymnsApplication).repository)
    }
```

**Inside onViewCreate, after attaching adapter to recyclerview:**

```
hymnViewModel.allHymns.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { words ->
            // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
            words?.let { adapter.submitList(it) }
        })
```